# jQuery & PHP : Resizing, refresh & crop

Tags: php, jquery, image, resize, crop

Hi there & thanks for reading:
I'm sorry if my question is a duplicate but browsed & couldn't find an answer..Although I figured my issue is rather 'standard':
I have a form with various inputs (personnal details, etc...) & I need the user to upload an image, so that he / she can then crop / select an area to be finally uploade & saved.

I have been successully using PHP server side resizing to upload  and show the resized image. No issue. This appears to be achieved mainly using the action tag from the form to redirect to the phps script.

The image, depending on wether it is "large" or "Wide", would be resized & reloaded using the resized width / height of the final image, the final size being also either "Tall" or "Wide"...

I would then want the user to be able to select an area from the resized image so that he "captures" an area in the image, without it being distorted...
There are plenty of scripts out there doing this'independently', but all apparently work similarly to the above ie. using the form's action tag to do the PHP server side stuff of cropping (usually using hidden inputs (x,y, w,h...) dynamically updated using jQuery...), such as imageareaselect...

So... My question would be **how could I resize, upload the resized image to be recropped, all within the same form ?**

Many thanks for your help

Regards,
JMB

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to try some sort of proven solution instead of rewriting everything.

Something similar to [Cropper](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/). There's a [PHP example here](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/tree/master/examples/crop-avatar) too.

There's definitely lots of options with Cropper. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but there's options to either crop the image in the backend (PHP) or on the frontend (JS). This means that the image doesn't need to upload to the server before the image is cropped. It allows you to only get the cropped picture in the backend.

Other Options:

- https://github.com/acornejo/jquery-cropbox
- https://github.com/trepmag/jrac
- https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image
- No frontend just backend: https://github.com/stojg/crop